# How to add dynamic products in line_items array in woocommerce rest api. I

Tags: arrays, foreach, woocommerce

Have tried something like this:

```
foreach($data[line_items] as $products){['product_id' =>
$products->product_id, 'quantity' => $products->quantity, ], }
```

But, no luck.